# End of life of IBM JDK/JRE 5?

Tags: upgrade, java

Is there an announced end of life/end of support-date for the ibm jdk 5 
(on Solaris/SPARC and Linux/x64)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the IBM JDK 5 (for AIX) happens to be [supported until 2012](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/aix/service.html). I couldn't find any explicit dates for Linux/x64 series; you might want to check with IBM itself.

Secondly, I'm not sure if IBM has released a JRE or SDK against Solaris/SPARC; the version of the JDK used in Solaris usually tends to be the Sun JDK which would hold good even for WebSphere.

Comment: re: Solaris; certainly, in WAS7 (Java 6) IBM use a licensed version of the Sun JDK with some of the libraries replaced; not sure what that means for support.

Comment: @McDowell, I'm unsure of whether IBM licensed it, or relies on the one present in the OS. WebLogic Server for instance, relies on the OS bundled JDK and does not install any of its own. It doesn't make a lot of sense for IBM to license the Sun JDK and embed it in WAS 7, unless they intend to port some of the features from the JDK for AIX. But in any case, you're right in that the impact of using a licensed version usually depends on the nature of the license and how much support IBM can afford.

Comment: all a bit off topic, this, but I had to go hunting to straighten out my facts. The WAS6 Redbook says the "JDK bundled with WebSphere Application Server on Solaris (SPARC and x64) is Sun JDK with IBM modifications." The IBM Java 5 & 6 docs say "IBM® does not supply a software developer kit or runtime environment for the Sun Solaris platform." http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/diagnosis/60.html If you run '/opt/.../AppServer/java/java -version' in WAS7/Solaris it reports an IBM version string. I imagine that support continues for the lifetime of the product.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of your product, you can check the [IBM Software Support Lifecycle](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycle/).

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle/Sun JDK 5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jdk5-jsp-142662.html) has reached the end of its support life.  I'd guess that the same is true for IBM's version as well if it's going to keep up.

Comment: I am not sure on this, because WebSphere 6.1 is not in its EOL period (even more, there wasn't even an EOL announcement yet), but Websphere 6.1 is bundled with the IBM JDK 5). I am looking for a webpage which prove your thoughts?

Comment: It's a good bet that IBM Java 5.0 will be in service while WebSphere 6.1 remains in service.

Comment: Oracle/Sun offers extended support even for Java 1.4 through Java for Business.   An interesting thing is that the Java included in OpenSolaris 9.06 was Java for Business.  http://www.sun.com/software/javaforbusiness/getit_download.jsp